# CE# pin pulsed low by ARM when configured

Tags: arm, ram

I have an STM32F2 that has a "Flexible Static Memory Controller" (FSMC). For some reason, when I configure the Chip Enable (CE#) pin of my PSRAM as a FSMC pin, the STM32 will pull the pin low (by default the pin is pulled high with an external pull-up).

The reason I ask is because this CE# pulse maybe explain why the [very first read/write operation fails](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35405/psram-first-operation-bogus-later-operations-fine) on my PSRAM.

Why is there such a pulse? Does STM have detailed documentation for it's Flexible Static Memory Controller explaining this behaviour?

Comment: Do you configure the CE# pin with the normal GPIO configuration? In that case, it might help to set it high before you configure it as output (or before you configure it to be a FSMC pin).

Comment: I do not configure the `CE#` pin as output, I configure it as "Alternate Function FSMC".

Comment: But configuring it that way implicitly configures it as output (since FSMC_NE[x] must be an output). But when that happens, AFAICS the value of the output data register gets written to the output. Try setting the value there to 1 before configuring the pin.

Comment: Ah, got you. I tried that, but I still see this pulse when calling the function `GPIO_Init`.

Comment: Is GPIO_Init() something you have written by yourself, or is it part of a library? Could it be that it sets its own state for the output pin? (I was assuming that you do the configuration by writing to all of the registers manually). If it's your code, can you post it?

Comment: `GPIO_Init` is part of the ARM standard library, and will modify the low level registers for me. I just have to pass it the right configuration options.

Comment: @hli - if the GPIO level is high, and you switch to the FSMC function, where it's also high, you shouldn't get a low pulse. This looks like a hardware bug to me.

Comment: @stevenh - I wanted to find out whether this might be a bug in the code. Could have been that, for some reason, some code sets the output to 0 when changing its state. I have just looked into the 'STM32F2 standard peripheral library V1.1.0', and the code there looks fine. So it really seems to be a hardware problem. I agree with you - a 1 in this register should not create a pulse when its function is changed. (The example code also doesn't seem to do anything special)

Comment: There is an Errata for the FSMC that is similar. But it talks about a dummy read being performed at the end of a cycle, not the beginning. And in any case, the workaround is "None". http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/ERRATA_SHEET/DM00027213.pdf

Comment: @embedded.kyle: Thanks for that. Turns out that my memory accesses are asynchronous, not synchronous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks perfectly normal to have \$\mathrm{\overline{CE}}\$ low for an external memory controller. The external memory will ignore all signals if \$\mathrm{\overline{CE}}\$ is high. \$\mathrm{\overline{CE}}\$ is often logically combined with the output of a partial address decoder to avoid several devices simultaneously accessing the databus.

You probably won't have pin conflicts with GPIO as long as you don't change the pin's function from FSMC to GPIO.

Comment: But is it normal to have `CE#` pulsed low before I make a read or write operation?

Comment: @Randomblue - If by "pulsed" you mean going low and back high again, then no, that's not normal. It should go low as the start of the I/O operation, and stay low until it's finished.

Comment: There is a pulse (low then back high again) when I initialise the pin (without any I/O). For I/O operations, it goes low and back high when it's finished, as expected.

Comment: @Randomblue - the pulse looks harmless to me, and shouldn't affect subsequent actions. Shouldn't happen though, and IMO could be a hardware bug.

Comment: You're probably right, but I'm investigating all options to find an explanation for [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/35405/psram-first-operation-bogus-later-operations-fine).

Comment: @Randomblue - Yes, I read that one, but I have no answer for it either, otherwise I would have posted one, obviously :-). Success with the search for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think this could be causing your issue, you should be able to have CE start out high when configuring the pin.
This sounds like it could be a small silicon issue, but getting any info from ST will probably be difficult (I just had a similar issue with SPI SS on an STM32F1, but the documentation is very misleading, the issue has been asked about on the ST forums for ~2 years and ST are yet to comment...)

Anyway, to test maybe you can keep the pin set as a normal GPIO and toggle it as necessary during a read/write. If the first operation succeeds like this then it looks like that's your problem.
Also (as hli suggests) if you haven't set the GPIO->ODR register before initialising the pin (whether you try it as AF or normal), try doing this (i.e. set ODR bit high so it hopefully starts out that way)
I did a similar thing with the SPI, controlling the SS pin in software.

Comment: That's a good suggestion (to drive the pin manually) but I'm afraid the timing requirements are too subtle that I would probably get them wrong.

Comment: True - I was only thinking of it as a way to confirm the cause of the problem though, not to use as a solution. I think the "solution" would maybe be to just do the first R/W twice.